# Google Cloud Storage Error When Using Ampersand (&) in Filename on Dev Server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

When saving a file using the Google Cloud Storage Python Client API on the development server, and the filename has an ampersand, the API throws an error.

The [cloud storage documentation on filenames](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-naming?hl=en#objectnames) says nothing about not being able to use ampersands in the filename. Is this a bug with the Google Cloud Storage Python API or am I doing something wrong?

My code, more or less:

```
import cloudstorage
f = cloudstorage.open("/my_bucket/my&file.txt", "w")
f.write("foo")
f.close()
```

The traceback that I get (partially redacted):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    f.close();
  File "libs\cloudstorage\storage_api.py", line 787, in close
    self._flush(finish=True)
  File "libs\cloudstorage\storage_api.py", line 841, in _flush
    self._send_data(data, self._written, file_len)
  File "libs\cloudstorage\storage_api.py", line 874, in _send_data
    {'upload_path': self._path_with_token})
  File "libs\cloudstorage\errors.py", line 141, in check_status
    raise ServerError(msg)
ServerError: Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 500.
Path: ...
Request headers: {'accept-encoding': 'gzip, *', 'x-goog-api-version': '2', 'content-range': 'bytes 0-2/3'}.
Response headers: {'server': 'Development/2.0', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'date': 'Mon, 27 Jul 2015 00:42:29 GMT'}.
Body: ''.
Extra info: {'upload_path': '...'}.
```

Would be surprised if this is a bug. This seems exactly like the type of thing a decent test suite would check.

Comment: I just checked and I was able to create an object named "my&file.txt" without a problem. Are you running a recent version of the library?

Comment: I don't think the ampersand is the issue. It looks like dev server dbase got corrupted. How does one go about debugging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity: had a similar problem except there was no ampersand in the filename. What fixed it was clearing the contents of the folder passed as `--storage_path` to `dev_appserver.py` (or adding it if it's not there ie: `/path/to/appengine/dev_appserver.py --storage_path=~/tmp`)

Possible source of this problem: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12976 - the above works as a quick fix though